# Generic resource service and meta with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I'm using [this approach](https://betterprogramming.pub/a-generic-http-service-approach-for-angular-applications-a7bd8ff6a068) in my app for api but it returns only an array of objects, for the project I need pagination and other meta.
How I can do that, thanks.

Comment: You can add pagination using the array you got.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your API is set up to read query parameters (naming and such), I would use the following pattern:

```js
public getItems(page: number = 1, per_page: number = 10) {
  const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
                                   .append('page', `${page}`)
                                   .append('per_page', `${per_page}`);
  return this.http.get<Item[]>(`${API_URL}`, { params });
}
```

`HttpParams` is an immutable object, which is why they are being set this way. And since there are defaults for the method parameters, you don't ever need to specify them. Passing parameters this way will result in a URL like `/api/route?page=1&per_page=10`

One side note - normally if pagination (or other "meta" as you mention) is needed for the request, that data is usually in the response as well. If this is true, the above code would need to be updated:

```js
// outside your service
interface ApiResponse<T> {
  pagination: {
    page: number;
    per_page: number;
    total_items: number;
    total_pages: number;
  }
  meta: unknown;
  
  // now when referencing ApiResponse, you can safely type the items being returned as an array of that item
  data: T[];
}

class Service {
  public getItems(page: number = 1, per_page: number = 10): Observable<ApiResponse<Item>> {
    const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
                                   .append('page', `${page}`)
                                   .append('per_page', `${per_page}`);

    // return the whole response body so consumers are aware of current pagination state
    return this.http.get<ApiResponse<Item>>(`${API_URL}`, { params });

   // OR, if you want to ignore the pagination and extract just the Items
   return this.http.get<ApiResponse<Item>>(`${API_URL}`, { params }).pipe(
     map((resp) => resp.data)
   );
  }
}
```